# how to retrieve parameters in web.xml jboss

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

made an application api rest and I need to recover parameters web.xml but not as I am using jboss 7.1

```
WEB-INF
     --lib
        --web.xml
```

Comment: What type of parameters?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis type text <context-param>
    <param-name>myParam</param-name>
    <param-value>value</param-value>
</context-param>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need access to the `ServletContext`. You can get it in different ways depending on where you want access to the `context-param`.

You can then call its [`getInitParameter(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
ServletContext ctx = ...;
String value = ctx.getInitParameter("your-param-name");
```

Comment: should extend HttpServlet, because I have doubts because it is api restful  would not apply? Sign the petition and want to obtain the parameters of the web.xml, the method is post

Comment: @Oxxi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Extending `HttpServlet` has nothing to do with designing a restful API.

Comment: sorry I missed something, it's the first time I did a rest api, and I find it somewhat complex jboss

Comment: @Oxxi Jboss, servlets, Java, etc. are unrelated to the concept of RESTful architecture. You should start by learning the Servlet API if you plan to use it to develop an application with a RESTful architecture and API.

Comment: The solution was to add a file type properties, and use the following code to obtain the parameters: public String getProp(String name){
  Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
  try {
   InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
     .getResourceAsStream("./properties.properties");
     prop.load(inputStream);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  String p = prop.getProperty(name);
  
  return p;
 }